# SQL ORDER BY GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables (ENTRIES and USERS) linked by id, I want to select all the entries from the top 5 users only, and then order them by the COUNT of individual users entries.

```
USERS    ENTRIES

tom      entry1
mary     entry2
jane     entry3
tom      entry4
tom      entry5
```

and so on....
to display as

```
USERS    ENTRIES

tom      entry1
tom      entry4
tom      entry5
jane     entry3
mary     entry2
```

my code at the moment just orders by names but does not list by COUNT of entries

```
SELECT  ENTRIES.entry, USERS.NAME   FROM ENTRIES, USERS 
WHERE ENTRIES.USER_ID = USERS.ID 
ORDER BY USERS.NAME
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Oracle you can use windowing functions to get the total count for each user:

```
SELECT e.entry, 
  u.NAME,
  count(*) over(partition by u.name) Total
FROM ENTRIES e
INNER JOIN USERS u
  ON e.USER_ID = u.ID 
ORDER BY total desc, u.NAME
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5b48/3).

If you then want to return only the top 5 rows, then you can use:

```
select entry,
  name,
  total
from 
(
  SELECT e.entry, 
    u.NAME,
    count(*) over(partition by u.name) Total,
    rownum rn
  FROM ENTRIES e
  INNER JOIN USERS u
    ON e.USER_ID = u.ID
) 
where rn <= 5
ORDER BY total desc, NAME
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5b48/6)

Comment: Very neat thank you. That sorted the ordering issue nicely. Just saw the top 5 piece too. Thanks again!